# Writing a Query that extract two different date points

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working on a query that involves the following fields:

```
id
date
revenue
```

There is other stuff involved, but for the purposes of this, those are the only three you need to know.

So basically, a very standard statement with these fields would be something like:

```
SELCT 
id, 
date_trunc('month', date) AS month, 
SUM(revenue) AS total_rev
FROM
sample.table
```

Say I have a date where a change happened that impacted the performance of select IDs and I want to create two buckets: Revenue in the month before the change and revenue in the month proceeding the change.

But here's the other caveat. The dates in which this change was applied to certain IDs vary. For some it might have been June 2017 while for another it was November 2017. So that throws a bit of a wrench into for me. But what's helpful is that I already know the small group of IDs this is affiliated with. So I can put in a WHERE statement like

```
WHERE id IN ('12345', '67891', '11121')
```

I've got a lot of experience in BigQuery but not much in Redshift, so I could use some help!

Comment: First, you need to decide what you mean by "change." If you want the revenue for two sequential months, then they *can't* be spread over a 5-month period. Your two requirements are incompatible.

Comment: @jpaugh good point. Change basically means what was revenue in month when change was implemented and what was the prior months? So if ID 12345 was implemented in October of 2017 I want the revenue from that month and September 2017.

Comment: So, you want the revenue for that row (ID) for those two months? Or the revenue of everything for those two months?

Comment: If you want an aggregate, you can get the revenue *with* and *without* the change; but before and after don't really make sense, unless you're talking about timescales longer than the project itself (e.g. the year before it was implemented, and the year after).

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- create a table that stores the ID and date of change
- join it to revenue dataset by id and same/prev month related to change date
- do conditional aggregates based on whether it's the same month or the prev month

Like this:

```
create table change_log (id integer, date date);
insert into change_log values (1,'2017-11-01'),(2,'2017-12-01');

select 
id,
sum(case when date_trunc('month',r.date)=date_trunc('month',c.date) then revenue end) as revenue_change_month,
sum(case when date_trunc('month',r.date)<date_trunc('month',c.date) then revenue end) as revenue_prior_month
from revenue_table r
join change_log c
on r.id=c.id
and date_trunc('month',r.date) between dateadd(month,-1,date_trunc('month',c.date)) and date_trunc('month',c.date)
group by 1
```

this way it doesn't matter which month it actually is in the calendar, but it's the month of change and the prior month for every user, if I understood the question correctly

One caveat is that if the change is done at the end of the month there will be a little effect on the monthly figure of the change month. You might improve this to use the 30 days prior to change and 30 days following the change, that might work better depending on the billing model of your business.